# How can I rename an object using Non standard evaluation in R

Tags: r, tidyeval, non-standard-evaluation

**Context**

I have a named vector `q1 = 2`. The object name is stored in `a = 'q1'`.

I can change `q1`'s name by `names(q1) = 'this_is_name'`.

Then I trid to use non standard evaluation to change `q1`'s name.

I thought `names(q1) = 'new_name'` and `names(sym(a)) = 'new_name'` will do the same, but it is not.

**Question**

How can I rename the object that get access by `a` in R?

In other word, How can I make `names(sym(a)) = 'new_name'` do the same as `names(q1) = 'new_name'`.

**Reproducible code**

```
q1 = 2
names(q1) = 'this_is_name'
a = 'q1'


names(q1) = 'new_name' 

names(sym(a)) = 'new_name' # I expect the code should do the same as names(q1) = 'new_name'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually change the object `q1` you can use `get` and `assign`, both in base R

```r
assign(a, setNames(get(a), 'new_name'))

q1
#> new_name 
#>        2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This does not literally change the object.  It creates a new object of the same name overwriting the old object.  This is transparent to the user who may not care what is happening internally but just wanted to clarify what "change the object" means.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck yes, fair point. I guess that could potentially be an issue with very large objects where read/write time is a concern. Still, fairly succinct and transparent code for most use cases. Using your method (or even avoiding creating a new environment by using `attr(as.environment(find(a))[[a]], 'name') <- 'new_name'` ) might be better if performance was a worry.

Comment: My answer also makes a copy so I don't think there is a material performance difference. Note that `attr(as.environment(find(a))[[a]], 'name') <- 'new_name'`
results in an Error.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that we have run the code in the Note at the end (copied from the question) this changes the name of `q1`.  This does change the address of `q1` internally but it is transparent to the user who is not affected. It uses only base R and does not use `eval` -- the use of which is generally frowned upon.

```
e <- environment()
names(e[[a]]) <- "new name"

q1
## new name 
##        2
```

or as a one-liner

```
with(list(e = environment()), names(e[[a]]) <- "new name")

q1
## new name 
##        2
```

### Note

```
q1 = 2
names(q1) = 'this_is_name'
a = 'q1'
```

Comment: Why not shorten the first one : `names(environment()[[a]]) <- "new name"`

Comment: @Julien, Because it doesn't work.

Comment: Unless you know it's in global environment then `names(.GlobalEnv[[a]]) <- "new_name"` works